# How do I access a "Group" member after I run PS "Group-Object"

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server-2010

I have the sourcedata similar to the following denormalized table

```
DisplayName                  LogRecordCount LogRecordBytes
-----------                  -------------- --------------
Mailbox - Low,                    459          43756
Mailbox - Low,                    1628         185542
Mailbox - Low,                    2575         264474
Mailbox - Low,                     522          48813
Mailbox - Low,                     410         138212
Mailbox - Low,                    1057         200043
Mailbox - Freed                  3866        2170719
Mailbox - Freed                   606         370304
Mailbox - Freed                  4137        1939924
Mailbox - Freed                 3655        1654650
```

My goal is to write a summary similar to the following

```
DisplayName                  LogRecordCount  
-----------                  -------------- 
Mailbox - Low,                     6651            
Mailbox - Freed                   12264
```

The following code is very close to getting what I need, but the "DisplayName" isn't appearing.  The value of DisplayName is buried in the result of the [`Group-Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/dd347561.aspx) command.

```
$stats | ? {$_.DigestCategory -eq 'LogBytes'} | group MailboxGuid | %{
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        MailboxGuid = $_.Name
        LogRecordBytes = ($_.Group | Measure-Object LogRecordBytes -Sum).Sum
        DisplayName   = $_.Group.DisplayName
    }
}| sort-object LogRecordBytes |  ft -a DisplayName, MailboxGuid, LogRecordBytes
```

**Question**

What is the proper syntax for  `DisplayName   = $_.Group.DisplayName` to display the display name in the results?

Comment: It's hard for us to help you because you're grouping by a property we can't see. The properties you group by are the only static ones. So for each group(1 group per `MailboxGuid`), there can be multiple values of `DisplayName`. If you only want `DisplayName` and `LogRecordCount`, why bother grouping by `MailboxGuid`?

Comment: @Graimer Let's assume MailboxGuid == Displayname for all logical operations.  It's possible that there are two display names of "john smith".  That is why I use the Guid.  I'll update the source data

Comment: okey, so there can only be displayname per group? If so, does this work: `DisplayName   = $_.Group | % { $_.DisplayName }` (replace with your current `displayname` code)

Comment: @Graimer You are definitely onto something.  The Group object contains several other objects.  Every object has the same name.  I only need one of those objects.

Comment: In other words I get for row1: `{Mailbox - Jsmith, Mailbox - Jsmith,Mailbox - Jsmith,Mailbox - Jsmith,}`  Brackets included

Comment: How about this: `DisplayName   = $_.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName -Unique`

Comment: @Graimer  That did it!!!!!!!!  Add that as an answer and I'll send 25 points your way

Comment: I've added it as an answer now ;) Glad i could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap out your `DisplayName = ..` line with the following:

```
DisplayName = $_.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName -Unique
```

If for some magical reason there are different `DisplayName` values in the group, you will get an array like `{value1, value2},` but normally it will return a single name only :)

Answer (score 0):

Graimer's answer is perfectly fine, but you could also just pluck the `DisplayName` from the first element of the group, assuming all group elements have the same value for `DisplayName`

```
DisplayName = $_.Group[0].DisplayName
```

Just wanted to let you know of another alternative.